# Can not change UILabel text color

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uicolor

I want to change the UILabel text color but I can't change the color, This is how my code looks like.

```
UILabel *categoryTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 16)];
categoryTitle.text = @"abc";
categoryTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
categoryTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
categoryTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
categoryTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
categoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:188 green:149 blue:88 alpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:categoryTitle];
[categoryTitle release];
```

The label text color is white ,not my custom color.

Thank for any help.

Comment: if you get confused on this, as a test use .. **[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor]** and so on.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

UIColor's RGB components are scaled between 0 and 1, not up to 255.

Try

```
categoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(188/255.f) green:... blue:... alpha:1.0];
```

---

In Swift:

```
categoryTitle.textColor = UIColor(red: 188/255.0, green: ..., blue: ..., alpha: 1)
```

Comment: Hi @KennyTM.Can I know why we have to use divide our value with 255

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS: To convert the values from 0 ... 255 (0xff) to 0.0 ... 1.0

Comment: If we already done this division and having those 0.5,0.6,0.3 for RGB respectively, How can we give that value.

Answer (score 8):

May be the better way is

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.myLabel setTextColor:color];
```

Thus we have colored text

Comment: The OP specifically wanted to use a **custom colour**, not just a preset colour, so using a preset is not a viable solution. The accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: The OP should not use a custom colour, it's too hard  :)

Comment: "**Too hard**"? God... (keeping sarcasm up!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, where alpha is opacity and others is Red,Green,Blue chanels-

```
self.statusTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(233/255.f) green:(138/255.f) blue:(36/255.f) alpha:1];
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, they are not connected in InterfaceBuilder.

Text colour`(colorWithRed:(188/255) green:(149/255) blue:(88/255))` is correct, may be mistake in connections,

backgroundcolor is used for the background colour of label and textcolor is used for property textcolor.

Answer (score 1):

Add attributed text color in swift code.

Swift 4:

```
  let greenColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 190/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)
  let attributedStringColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : greenColor];

  let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: attributedStringColor)
  label.attributedText = attributedString
```

for Swift 3:

```
  let greenColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 190/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)
  let attributedStringColor : NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : greenColor];


  let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: attributedStringColor as? [String : AnyObject])
  label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Good way to set the attribute for Label.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is wrong 
categoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:188 green:149 blue:88 alpha:1.0];

// This should be  
categoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:188/255 green:149/255 blue:88/255 alpha:1.0];

// In the documentation, the limit of the parameters are mentioned.
```

[colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621930-colorwithred?changes=_2&language=objc)