# Dynamically change the text color of UILabel base on the background of this label

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I am interested how does iPhone built in photos app changes the clock's color when I previewing an image as a wallpaper. I have been searching for 2 days but no success. I understand that the method should analyze pixel's color behind the label. But going through each pixel seems to be inefficient. Could somebody guide me through this?

Comment: How does clock's color changes? Could you please elaborate a bit, for instance by uploading a snapshot?

Comment: What's behind the label? Is it a UIImageView? This talks about how to get RGB from a UIImage at specific pixel positions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics

Comment: @Munahil It changes dynamically. When you drag a photo and something too bright appears behind the label turns to black, otherwise white. I don't have the phone right now.

Comment: @MikeStrand suppose I got those RGBA values but what's next?

Comment: You would programmatically set the label text color with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532409/can-not-change-uilabel-text-color

Comment: @MikeStrand you didn't get the idea. I don't have just a point. I have a rectangle which is UILabel's frame. Thus, base on the color of the rect(which can consist of many colors), I need to setup label's color. The only reason I am asking this question is I want to know what to do. Should I calculate an average color or what and e.t.c

Comment: I guess it depends on the visual effect you want, but yeah - getting an average would be a good start and then picking something in contrast I'm guessing is what you want. https://github.com/mxcl/UIImageAverageColor/blob/master/UIImage%2BAverageColor.m

Comment: I think, you are looking for this:
[color from background image][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456288/text-color-based-on-background-image