# UIView contains label how to change the color of the label iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I created UIView which contains label. I need to change the color of the label. I am using the following code it is not working. Not going into If statement.

```
UIView *tabViewContent = [self.dataSource viewPager:self viewForTabAtIndex:index];
for (UIView *view in [tabViewContent subviews]) 
{
     //Check if the view is of UILabel class
     if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
     {
      //Cast the view to a UILabel
      UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
      //Set the color to label
      label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not change UILabel text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532409/can-not-change-uilabel-text-color)

Comment: @l'L'l Inside UIView there is a label. I want to change it.

Comment: @ Unheilig edited my question

Comment: can't you just create a global UILabel property then change it's textColor anywhere in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

what is variable subview?

Second choice is use tag to this UILabel

```
for (id *object in tabViewContent) {
     if (object.tag == MYTAG) {
      UILabel *label = (UILabel *)object;
      label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
}
```

Or you can scan all objects in view

```
for (id *object in self.view) {
     if (object.tag == MYTAG) {
      UILabel *label = (UILabel *)object;
      label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
}
```

i hope this help.

Comment: There's a method called `viewWithTag:`

Comment: getting this warning -  collection expression type uiview may not respond to countbyenumeratingwithstate:objects:count

Comment: Did you assign a tag to your label?